# jQuery DataTables - Calling multiple plug-ins? (date range / range search)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How do I combine these 2 plug-ins into my jquery datatables setup?

When I remove one of them, the one left over works (ex: remove date range, range search with numbers works). I've linked both below.

[Date Range Plug-in](https://datatables.net/extensions/datetime/examples/integration/datatables.html)

[Range Search Plug-in](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html)

After calling the DataTable, I'm then calling for the table.draw() for everything to update based on my input for either the range picker or the date picker.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
}
```

I'm thinking what I have wrong is how I've setup the $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push - I've checked TONS of times that my IDs are correct and that the data indexes are also correct. As mentioned, I remove one of these plug-ins and the other one works. I've tried a couple other examples I've found online, but coming up with nothing.

```
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
    var min = parseInt( $('#minNumber').val(), 10 );
    var max = parseInt( $('#maxNumber').val(), 10 );
    var risk = parseFloat( data[0] ) || 0;

    var minDateTime = minDate.val();
    var maxDateTime = maxDate.val();
    var date = new Date( data[1] );

    if ( ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) ||
         ( isNaN( min ) && risk <= max ) ||
         ( min <= risk   && isNaN( max ) ) ||
         ( min <= risk   && risk <= max ) )
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (
        ( minDateTime === null && maxDateTime === null ) ||
        ( minDateTime === null && date <= maxDateTime ) ||
        ( minDateTime <= date   && maxDateTime === null ) ||
        ( minDateTime <= date   && date <= maxDateTime )
    ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine the logic for your number range checker with the logic for your date range checker. You want all of the 4 input fields to be evaluated in a single `if` statement to determine whether a record should be hidden or displayed.

Currently they are operating as 2 independent pieces of code, one after the other.

Combine them with an `&&` operator:

```js
if (((isNaN(min) && isNaN(max)) ||
    (isNaN(min) && risk <= max) ||
    (min <= risk && isNaN(max)) ||
    (min <= risk && risk <= max)) &&
  (
    (minDateTime === null && maxDateTime === null) ||
    (minDateTime === null && date <= maxDateTime) ||
    (minDateTime <= date && maxDateTime === null) ||
    (minDateTime <= date && date <= maxDateTime)
  ))

{
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

---

The above logic may be hard to read - so an equivalent approach is the following:

```js
var withinRisk = ( 
    ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) ||
    ( isNaN( min ) && risk <= max ) ||
    ( min <= risk  && isNaN( max ) ) ||
    ( min <= risk  && risk <= max ) 
);

var withinDates = (
    ( minDateTime === null && maxDateTime === null ) ||
    ( minDateTime === null && date <= maxDateTime ) ||
    ( minDateTime <= date  && maxDateTime === null ) ||
    ( minDateTime <= date  && date <= maxDateTime )
); 

if (withinRisk && withinDates)  {
  return true;
} else {
  return false; 
}
```

Here, we keep the two range checks separate, and only combine them at the end.